# MySQL 5.7 InnoDB is extremely slow on spatial data compared to MySQL 5.6

Tags: innodb, performance, spatial, mysql-5.7, performance-tuning

I have a table `area` which contains *~300,000* rows. It is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `area` (
  `area_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `boundary` geometry NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `area_type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`area_id`),
  KEY `FK_7r1ppwayxh76te8c6jq3nrd71` (`area_type_id`),
  SPATIAL KEY `boundary` (`boundary`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=311998 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The execution times on MySQL *5.6.24* and the latest GA *5.7.9* vary greatly (two orders of magnitude) for the following query:

```
set @p = st_GeomFromText('POINT(14.822664 56.858916)');
select area_id from area where st_within(@p, boundary);
```

Although the result of the query ran on either system is *the same*, the execution times are not:

```
| MySQL 5.6.24-log (x86/Win32) | MySQL 5.7.9-log (x86_64/Win64) |
| ---------------------------- | ------------------------------ |
|                   0.0553 sec |                     8.5342 sec |
```

So, the newer MySQL version is **154 times slower**. Am I doing something wrong?

The `explain` looks as follows:

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra
| -- | ----------- | ----- | ---------- | ----- | ------------- | -------- | ------- | ---- | ---- | -------- | -----
| 1  | SIMPLE      | area  | NULL       | range | boundary      | boundary | 34      | NULL | 1    | 100.00   | Using where
```

---

**Edit:** Here is a [dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_uvSaA5pYmZk1LQ2JkMnFzcm8/view?usp=sharing) of the table which I used (~821mb).

Comment: dump - protected

Comment: Dump should work now I guess.

Comment: it interesting - plan the same, query statistic show - 12 rows examined, 4 returned to client, but time very long on 5.7

Comment: @a_vlad: So you can confirm the slow speed?

Comment: on windows and mac with 16gb of RAM, look like some fundamental problem. same 8 sec

Comment: Btw. I am having another issue with this which I [posted on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868449/mysql-5-7-st-contains-not-returning-all-matches-on-innodb-and-no-matches-on-myis) earlier. I think I should file a bug report.